# Adding object to a linked list c++

Tags: c++, object, linked-list

I am trying to add a object to my linked list, the problem is I am not sure how also the object its self is a base class with sub classes. Vehicle and Car,Van respectively.

The idea of the program is a vehicle rental system where the user can add a vehicle to the system and set certain variables about the vehicle such as: reg number engine size etc but also if the vehicle is a van or a car you the set further variables depending on the whether its a car or van.

For example if I want to add a Ford Van, I would enter the details such as engine size,model etc then i would specify that its a van allowing me to add further details contained within the van subclass.

If any of you can help me with being able to add an object to a linked list such that it meets the criteria I would be very thankful.

My code to insert a new node.

```
void linkedList::InsertNode(int regNo,double engine,string model,vehicle_type make)
{
Vehicle<int> vehicle(int,double,string,vehicle_type);

//create new node
nodePtr n=new node;
//make next point to null
n->next=NULL;
n->data=vehicle(regNo,engine,model,make);

//if we have a list set current pointer
if(head!=NULL)
{
    current=head;
    //checks if end
    while(current->next!=NULL)
    {
        current=current->next;
    }
    //connect last node to new node
    current->next=n;
}
else
{
    //new node is front of list if empty
    head=n;
}
}
```

Linkedlist.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;



class linkedList
{
template<class regNo>;
friend class Vehicle<int>;

typedef enum{ Car,Van} vehicle_type;

private:
typedef struct node                                                
{                                                               
  int data;               
  node* next;             
}*nodePtr;

nodePtr head;
nodePtr current;
nodePtr temp;

public:
linkedList();
void InsertNode(int regNo ,double engine,string model,vehicle_type make);
void SearchNode(int);
void PrintList();
void DeleteNode(int delData);
~linkedList();
};
```

vehicle.h

```
#pragma once

template<class regNo=int>
class Vehicle
{
public:
typedef enum{ Car,Van} vehicle_type;

protected:
vehicle_type make;
string model;
int regNo;
double engineSize;
bool rented;

public:
Vehicle(vehicle_type  make):model(""),regNo(reg),engineSize(engine),make(make),rented(false){};
char getMakeModel();
int getRegNo();
int getEngineSize();
bool getRented();
bool setRented(bool rented);
~Vehicle();

void listVehicle();
void addVehicle();
void removeVehicle(int delData);
void bookVehicle();
void displayDetails(int regNo);
void listCarsNotRented();
void listFiveDoor();
void listFordVansRented();
};
```

For clarification the linked listed will contain a list of many objects that holds information about a vehicle, what I need to do is add a vehicle(object) to the list.

The error occurs when trying to set the data within the node to the object I want.

Comment: Is this an assignment in which you have to implement a linked list yourself? If not, why not just use one of the many STL containers?

Comment: I have to implement the linked list myself yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't know how this will work:

`Vehicle<int> vehicle(int,double,string,vehicle_type);`

I think you meant to type this:

`Vehicle<int> vehicle(regNo,engine,model,vehicle_type);`

If you don't have an assignment or something for linked lists that you must implement linked lists yourself, I would recommend you to use Boost Linked lists instead of implementing your own: [Link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/intrusive/slist.html)

For the actual problem itself:

If you want to find out what type of object it is you're adding to the linked list, simply override methods for them to support sub-classes. So instead of adding to linked list by using primitives (int, double etc.) take a Vehicle object or Van object in order to add to the list. I don't know the code but it is something like this:

```
void linkedList::InsertNode(Van *pVan)
{
     Van newVan(*pVan); // You need a copy constructor for this
     // Set Van specific attributes like this:
     newVan->setEngineSize (123);

     //create new node
     nodePtr n = new node;
     //make next point to null
     n->next=NULL;
     n->data= newVan; // You need a copy constructor for this

     //if we have a list set current pointer
     if(head!=NULL)
     {
         current=head;
         //checks if end
         while(current->next!=NULL)
         {
             current=current->next;
         }
         //connect last node to new node
         current->next=n;
     } else
     {
         //new node is front of list if empty
         head=n;
     }
}

void linkedList::InsertNode(Car *pCar)
{
     Car newCar(*pCar); // You need a copy constructor for this
     // Set Car specific attributes like this:
     newCar->setEngineSize (123);

     //create new node
     nodePtr n = new node;
     //make next point to null
     n->next=NULL;
     n->data= newCar; // You need a copy constructor for this

     //if we have a list set current pointer
     if(head!=NULL)
     {
         current=head;
         //checks if end
         while(current->next!=NULL)
         {
             current=current->next;
         }
         //connect last node to new node
         current->next=n;
     } else
     {
         //new node is front of list if empty
         head=n;
     }
}
```

So override the methods to support different classes. When you compile the code, it will automatically call the right method for you. For example if you have a Van and call insertNode function that you pass a reference of your new Van object, it won't call `void linkedList::InsertNode(Vehicle *pVehicle)` but will call `void linkedList::InsertNode(Van *pVan)`

My recommendations:
- Make a "tail" pointer that points to the end of the list, so that you won't go through a while loop each time you add an object.
- While implementing any additional containers, use "template"s for the data types.

Comment: I don't think it possible but is it possible to set variables of a base class using the constructor and not using setters?

Comment: Well if your base class is an abstract class (which is usually the case), then no. However in your derived classes, you can call the base class constructor to initialize base class. Here are two code snipplets, sorry about the formatting but you'll understand it. ---- Here is one with a regular base class: http://textsnip.com/0a4o40/csharp ----------- Here is one with the abstract base class: http://textsnip.com/ocbt7v/csharp ----------- Tell me if you need anymore information.